# Unable to add a mongod server in local network as shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to build a small cluster using mongodb sharding. In node1 and node2, mongod is started. In node1, config server and mongos are started. All listening 0.0.0.0 with exclusively allocated ports.

When I use mongo to login mongos in node1, I can add Node1 mongod as shard but when I try on Node2, an error occurs:

```
mongos> sh.addShard("<ip of node2 in local network>")
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "No common protocol found.", "code" : 126 }
```

I did some searching but few documentation is about this error.

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using? Are all your nodes running the same version?

Comment: @Stennie, all using 3.2.6